# Function for resizing matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I was wondering if there was a function that scales down matrices in R statistical software exactly like with image resizing. The function `imresize()` in MATLAB is exactly what I'm looking for (I believe it takes the average of the surrounding points, but I am not sure of this), but I am wondering if there is an R equivalent for this function.

This question has been posted before on this forum, but with reference to MATLAB, not R:
[Matlab "Scale Down" a Vector with Averages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741808/matlab-scale-down-a-vector-with-averages)
The post starting with "Any reason why you can't use the `imresize()` function?" is exactly what I am looking for, but in R, not MATLAB.

Say I have a latitude-longitude grid of temperatures around the world, and let's say this is represented by a 64*128 matrix of temperatures. Now let's say I would like to have the same data contained in a new matrix, but I would like to rescale my grid to make it a 71*114 matrix of temperatures around the world. A function that would allow me to do so is what I'm looking for (again, the imresize() function, but in R, not MATLAB)

Thank you.
Steve

Comment: This question looks identical to http://stackoverflow.com/q/10865489/602276

Comment: Several R image-manipulation packages have a "resize" -- like function, often to scale up or down.  It's also not hard to roll your own, depending on how you want to collapse the values -- average, or spline, etc.  So: what do you want: mean temperatures in your grid, or worst-case (e.g. max) temperatures, etc?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Do you have some particular `package::function`'s in mind?  I for one would be happy for *any* pointers you can provide. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I was probably thinking of `aggregate`, also in the `raster` package. (as is `disaggregate`).  I wrote a complex version of these tools to handle E-M wavefront propagation if anyone's interested.

Comment: It occurs to me, far too late, :-(  that this problem may best be handled in the general case with a kernel-based convolution approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do this is by using the function `resample()`, from the `raster` package.

I'll first show how you could use it to rescale your grid, and then give an easier-to-inspect example of its application to smaller raster objects

### Use `resample()` to resize matrices

```
library(raster)
m <- matrix(seq_len(68*128), nrow=68, ncol=128, byrow=TRUE)

## Convert matrix to a raster with geographical coordinates
r <- raster(m)
extent(r) <- extent(c(-180, 180, -90, 90))

## Create a raster with the desired dimensions, and resample into it
s <- raster(nrow=71, ncol=114)
s <- resample(r,s)

## Convert resampled raster back to a matrix
m2 <- as.matrix(s)
```

### Visually confirm that `resample()` does what you'd like:

```
library(raster)
## Original data (4x4)
rr <- raster(ncol=4, nrow=4)
rr[] <- 1:16
## Resize to 5x5
ss <- raster(ncol=5,  nrow=5)
ss <- resample(rr, ss)
## Resize to 3x3
tt <- raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
tt <- resample(rr, tt)
## Plot for comparison
par(mfcol=c(2,2))
plot(rr, main="original data")
plot(ss, main="resampled to 5-by-5")
plot(tt, main="resampled to 3-by-3")
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The answer posted by Josh O'Brien is OK and it helped me (for starting point), but this approach was too slow since I had huge list of data. The method below is good alternative. It uses `fields` and works much faster.

#### Functions

```
rescale <- function(x, newrange=range(x)){
  xrange <- range(x)
  mfac <- (newrange[2]-newrange[1])/(xrange[2]-xrange[1])
  newrange[1]+(x-xrange[1])*mfac
}

ResizeMat <- function(mat, ndim=dim(mat)){
  if(!require(fields)) stop("`fields` required.")

  # input object
  odim <- dim(mat)
  obj <- list(x= 1:odim[1], y=1:odim[2], z= mat)

  # output object
  ans <- matrix(NA, nrow=ndim[1], ncol=ndim[2])
  ndim <- dim(ans)

  # rescaling
  ncord <- as.matrix(expand.grid(seq_len(ndim[1]), seq_len(ndim[2])))
  loc <- ncord
  loc[,1] = rescale(ncord[,1], c(1,odim[1]))
  loc[,2] = rescale(ncord[,2], c(1,odim[2]))

  # interpolation
  ans[ncord] <- interp.surface(obj, loc)

  ans
}
```

#### Lets look how it works

```
## Original data (4x4)
rr <- matrix(1:16, ncol=4, nrow=4)
ss <- ResizeMat(rr, c(5,5)) 
tt <- ResizeMat(rr, c(3,3)) 

## Plot for comparison
par(mfcol=c(2,2), mar=c(1,1,2,1))
image(rr, main="original data", axes=FALSE)
image(ss, main="resampled to 5-by-5", axes=FALSE)
image(tt, main="resampled to 3-by-3", axes=FALSE)
```

[image: Resized matrix]